# Comparison of row with a column (named range)

Tags: excel, comparison

**My data:**

| TABLE 1 | Person1 | Person2 | Person3 | Person4 | Person5 | Person6 | Person7 | Person8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | A | B | C | D | E | E | F | F |
| Tuesday | B | F | D | C | E | E | F | A |
| Wednesday | C | D | A | F | E | E | F | F |

| PLACE |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |

**My question:**
I want to compare if on each day all the values from the named range `Place` are within the row of `Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,...` and if some are missing which one these are.
So, for `Wednesday` it should give a `"B" missing` withing the `IF` formula or whatever suggestion you have. `"E"` and `"F"` are not in `Place`, those should be ignored.

**What I tried so far:**
Research always led me to comparison of 2 columns instead of rows&columns.
I tried array functions like this one ($B3:$I3 == "Monday row" == "row1"):

```vb
=INDEX(Place;SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Place;$B3:$I3;0));(ROW(Place)-MIN(ROW(Place))+1);"");ROWS($A$1:A1)))
```

> Error: Many "helper" columns needed for inidividual rows to compare. Also "#NUM!" values even if all vlaues from `Place` occur or just one is missing.

I got startet with many `COUNTIF` formulas like

```
=COUNTIF(row1;INDEX(Place;1))+COUNTIF(row1;INDEX(Place;2))+COUNTIF(row1;INDEX(Place;3))+COUNTIF(row1;INDEX(Place;4))
```

giving me a `"4"` when all values occur and lower values if some or all are missing. But how can I connect getting these number to "seeing" which values are missing to cause the "lower than 4" number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this UDF will give you the result you want.

```
Function Check(Data As Range) As String
    ' 296
    
    ' Data specifies one row from the table excl column #1
    Dim Fun()       As String               ' function return value
    Dim i           As Long                 ' index to Fun()
    Dim Places      As Variant              ' array of range "Place"
    Dim R           As Long                 ' loop counter; Places
    Dim Match       As Variant              ' result of Match() function
    
    ' this command will slow down your workbook.
    '   If inconvenient (too sluggish), remove it.
    ' If removed, the UDFs in the worksheet may not recalculate as you expect.
    '   Click "Calculate Now" on the ribbon's 'Formulas' tab to update.
    Application.Volatile
    
    ' the named range "Places" must exist in the worksheet
    ' in the sample it's B10:B13
    Places = ActiveSheet.Range("Places").Value
    ReDim Fun(UBound(Places))
    
    For R = 1 To UBound(Places)
        Match = Application.Match(Places(R, 1), Data, 0)
        If IsError(Match) Then
            i = i + 1
            Fun(i) = Places(R, 1)
        End If
    Next R
    
    If i Then
        Fun(0) = "Missing: "
    Else
        Fun(0) = "All present"
    End If
    ReDim Preserve Fun(i)
    Check = Replace(Join(Fun, ", "), ",", vbNullString, 1, 1)
End Function
```

The code must be pasted to a standard code module. You have to insert it, and it will have a name like "Module1" by default, which you can change. Don't use any of the existing code modules. Call the function from anywhere in the workbook by entering syntax similar to this: `=Check(C3:J3)`. Here C3:J3 defines the 2nd to last columns of your table, excluding "Monday", and the result will evaluate items listed in this range against the range `Places`.

Comment: Would there have been a way with just formulas? Just being curious...

Comment: If you question my religion, I would say yes. But if you ask me how long it would take me to develop such a formula I must admit that I don't know.

Comment: If thinking of formula solution, can you say what version of Excel you have?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2019 or above, you can use Textjoin with Countif like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(COUNTIF(B2:I2,Places)=0,Places,""))
```

where Places is a named range $A$6:$A$9.

[image]

You have to repeat a lot of the formula or use a separate column to make it put "All present" or "Missing"

```
=IFS(SUM(COUNTIF(B2:I2,Places))=ROWS(Places),"All present",SUM(COUNTIF(B2:I2,Places))=0,"All missing",TRUE,"Missing "&TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(COUNTIF(B2:I2,Places)=0,Places,"")))
```

unless you have Excel 365 where you can use Let to avoid repetition:

```
=LET(counts,COUNTIF(B2:I2,Places),
total,SUM(counts),
IFS(total=ROWS(Places),"All present",total=0,"All missing",TRUE,"Missing "&TEXTJOIN(",",,IF(counts=0,Places,""))))
```

If you don't have Textjoin, I don't think there is any alternative to using individual Countif's or Matches.